# NLog not creating text log file

Tags: asp.net, logging, nlog

I have followed the example here to add logging to an output file on my ASP.net website: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial

When I run the website locally on my PC I see that it creates a text log file **file.txt** in the same directory as my website is in.  But when I upload it to a live server it does not create a text file in the same location as my website.

This is my nlog.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="false"
  internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Why would this be? Do I have to make any further changes for when its on a live server?

Comment: Are you sure the user your server is running as has permissions to write to that directory? What happens if you try writing it to the App_Data folder within the website? What does the internal log say?

Comment: Apologies but I'm new to server logging. How do I find out what permissions the user of the server has? Do I need to contact my hosting provider to find that out?

Comment: Ah, 3rd party host. Most likely the user your application is running as can't write to the root of the website. But try logging into the App_Data folder in the root of your site and see if that works.

Comment: I have created a folder called App_Data in the root of my site and added <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=ApplicationData}/file.txt" /> to my config file but I still do not see any output logging text file in it.

Comment: you can set `throwExceptions="true"` and see what will be reported by NLog.

Comment: I see that the default logfile for Nlog is "internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log". Does this relate to the location on the 3rd party hosting server? And if so how will I be able to access this location???

Comment: What do you mean "does this relate"? Wherever that points is where the log files will be, assuming it can write there. So of course you need to specify a location it has proper permissions to. Did you try following Julian's advice?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I added a logs folder to my App_Data folder and put a blank .txt file in it so the directory would get copied when publishing. But, even with my target set to `<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}App_Data\logs\${shortdate}.log" />` it still won't write in production. Locally, it writes directly to the App_Data/logs directory. I actually have another directory in the App_Data directory and it has exactly the same permissions as the logs directory.